# Can't AJAXify functioning search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Adapted [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) to work on my show page in my app, and the search is working fine, but it's not instant (nor, weirdly, is it on keyup, though it does work on submit, which I thought I hadn't coded).

As mentioned in my updates below, when I try to fix the problem by adding "remote: true" to the form_tag (a deviation from the RailsCast), the search stops functioning altogether. Any idea what's going on?

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag @post, :method => 'get', :id => "posts_search", class: "search_form squeeze form-inline" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
    placeholder: "Search titles:", id: "search_field" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn squeeze search" %>
  </p>
  <div id="list"><%= render 'search' %></div>
<% end %>
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<ul class="blog_links">
<% @posts.first(@link_num).each do |p| %>
    <li class="total_hover">
        <%= p.name %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("search")) %>");
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end



 def search
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse
    render json: { results: @posts }
 end
```

**post.rb**

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

**javascripts/posts.js.coffee**

```
$ -> 
  $("#posts_search input").keyup ->
    $.get $("#posts_search").attr("action"), $("#posts_search").serialize(), null, "script"
    false
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/search', to: 'posts#search'
```

**EDIT** -- When I add "remote: true" to my form_tag, the search stops working entirely. As in, it neither searches upon keyup nor upon submission.

Interestingly, though, my network (in the inspector) seems to be making a GET request whenever (and only when) I press submit. That request includes my search term, so that, for example, when I was on the page of the post called "This is a very long post name" (with a slugged url) and I search "long", the request is this:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/this-is-a-really-long-post-title?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=long
```

That URL doesn't actually show up in the URL bar, but it's there in the network requests.

**EDIT** -- Followed Paulo's suggestion to move remote:true to the right place in my form_tag. So:

```
<%= form_tag @post, remote: true, method: 'get', id: "posts_search", class: "search_form squeeze form-inline" do %>
```

Once again, having remote:true stops the search function in general. When I inspect that element, I get this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts/this-is-a-really-long-post-title" class="search_form squeeze form-inline" data-remote="true" id="posts_search" method="get">
```

"this-is-a-really-long-post-title" is the title of the post on the page where I'm conducting the search. It's also the slug in the url. I think, therefore, the problem may be the action I'm calling in this tag. '/posts' was suggested, but a) I'm conducting this search on the show, not the index page, and b) when I try '/posts', which produces this form tag:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="search_form squeeze form-inline" data-remote="true" id="posts_search" method="get">
```

I get this error (in the console inspector) when I press search (and a similar one whenever I type in the search box, so keyup is working).

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search= 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8476
 send jquery.js:8476
 jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7931
 $.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js:110
 $.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js:175
 (anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js:392
 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3046
 elemData.handle jquery.js:2722
```

**EDIT** -- If I remove the remote:true, as in the Railscast, and use @post in the path, I get this weird combo of behavior:

- While my javascript no longer has any action associated with the *submission* of the form, when I submit a search, the page fully reloads with the search performed and displayed correctly.
- When I just type, the Firebug console shows a request firing with every key press (which makes sense, given my JS), but nothing happens on the actual page.

Again, when I add remote:true, nothing happens on the page at all.

**EDIT** -- If I delete the contents of posts.js.coffee, the search performs exactly the same. As in, it works if there's no remote:true in the form_tag, but only upon pressing submit. Why is it ignoring what's going on in that .js.coffee file?

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO JVNILL'S ANSWER**

I replaced the code in posts.js.coffee with what jvnill suggested. Now the search doesn't function at all, but it seems that this is a result of the search function being called in the javascript not doing its thing, cause the preventDefault call seems to be working, and when I search (here, for "really"), the browser seems to be sending my keypresses as params:

```
Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rea&_=1362073395037" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 09:43:17 -0800
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"rea", "_"=>"1362073395037"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%rea%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 21.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=real&_=1362073395038" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 09:43:17 -0800
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"real", "_"=>"1362073395038"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%real%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 49.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=real&_=1362073395039" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 09:43:17 -0800
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"real", "_"=>"1362073395039"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%real%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 16.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=reall&_=1362073395040" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 09:43:17 -0800
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"reall", "_"=>"1362073395040"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%reall%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 15.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=reall&_=1362073395041" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 09:43:17 -0800
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"reall", "_"=>"1362073395041"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%reall%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.6ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand you correctly but with your original setup, you have a working search right? You just want to submit the form via ajax?  Plus you have a delayed search response?  I hope the following code fixes both of these issues

```
@search = ->
  $.get $('#posts_search').attr("action"), $("#posts_search").serialize(), null, "script"

$ ->
  $('#posts_search input').keypress -> search()

  $('#posts_search').submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    search()
```

You can use keypress instead of keyup or use a plugin that observes changes to the search field like [delayedObserver](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/DelayedObserver).  You also need to observe when the form is submitted and use ajax instead of the normal form submit

UPDATE: just noticed that the log shows that you're going to the index action and it's actually rendering an html template which means you don't have a js template. so copy `show.js.erb` to `index.js.erb`.

UPDATE: editing index action. one more thing you need to add is a `format.js` line inside the respond_to block so it doesn't default to html.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! So to clarify, the only problem I've got is that the search function isn't instantaneous AJAX. I want users typing to narrow the field of posts as they type. Currently, the search works on submission only, and shows the query in the URL. I replaced my posts.js.coffee file with the lines you suggested, but the problem persists. How do I make sure the form is submitted using AJAX, as you suggest?

Comment: Sorry for the cluelessness. I'm really quite bad with Javascript/AJAX. Trying to teach myself how it fits into a Rails program and how to code it, but most of these functions/concepts are still way over my head.

Comment: EDIT -- So actually, when I added your code, it now didn't search at all! I think what's happening is the preventDefault() call is working, but the search function isn't doing anything (or is returning the full posts list or something). Also of interest is that the server log DOES seem to be registering keypress. I'll paste a couple lines of its output when I type in a search above.

Comment: Sorry. Should have mentioned that. I already did. This was all copied from a Railscast that did search in the index action, and when I got desperate, I switched everything over. So the search now takes place in index.html.erb, the js.erb file is index, and I have this line at the top of both the index and search actions in the posts controller: @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse -- all of which is now in the updated post above

Comment: can you show your index action? you probably need a respond_to block there to handle js requests

Comment: Just put it up there. That definitely could be the problem. It responds to JSON, but there's nothing in it about JS.

Comment: THANKS! It worked. If I could select your answer five times I would. I've been trying to figure this out on and off for days! Super frustrating. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote option to your form_tag. Check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

```
<%= form_tag('/posts', :remote => true) %>
# => <form action="/posts" method="post" data-remote="true">
```

Use firebug to inspect if the form generated has the data-remove tag to true.

Comment: I was wondering why that wasn't in the Railscast. But when I add "remote: true" to the form tag, for some reason the search does NOTHING. Nothing on keyup, and nothing when I press submit.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Make sure you add the options to the correct hash parameter.

Comment: Just switched things around. It's still behaving as in my comment above, but I added the inspector/firebug output to my question above.